# Используя 'TimePickerDialog' не могу отследить событие изменения времени в 'TimePicker'

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Я использую `DialogFragment` для отображения в нем `TimePickerDialog`. Проблема заключается в том, что в `onCreateDialog` я задаю заголовок диалога `dialog.setTitle(selectTitle());`, а после изменения времени в `TimePicker` (выбор часов/минут) в заголовке отображается выбранное время. Мне нужно чтобы всегда отображался мой заголовок.
Я попробовал сделать так: имплементировал `TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener`, где можно переопределить метод `onTimeChanged`, но ничего не работает.
Вот мой код:

```
public class FragmentTimePicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,
        TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // устанавливаем текущее время для TimePicker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // создаем TimePickerDialog и возвращаем его
        TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog( getActivity(), this, hour, minute, true);
        dialog.setTitle(selectTitle());

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "HELP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hours, int minute) {
        if (getTag().equals("dfTimePickerFrom")) {
            DialogShiftTime.etTimeFrom.setText(formatTime(hours, minute));
        } else DialogShiftTime.etTimeTo.setText(formatTime(hours, minute));
    }
```

Comment: `onTimeChanged()` будет срабатывать только после окончания выбора времени (то есть когда будет нажато ок)

Comment: а не `onTimeSet()` разве для окончания выбора времени?